# Not a number error (NAN) doing collision detection in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, physics, nan

I have a set of balloons that I am trying to get to bounce off of each other like balls.  When I start to move them and then detect collision, the routine for the collisions eventually returns a NAN for the velocity of the balloons.  I end up with a position of something like x=270, y= -nan(0x400000).  I've been looking at the code all day and I still can't find the error, any help would be appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
 - (void)MoveBalloons {

    for (CurBalloon=1; CurBalloon <= NumBalloons; ++CurBalloon) {

    //check for edge hCurBalloont
    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.y > 456) {
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.y = 456;
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = -uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y;
    }
    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.y < 24) {
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.y = 24;
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = -uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y;
    }
    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.x > 289) {
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.x = 289;
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = -uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x;
    }
    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.x < 31) {
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.x = 31;
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = -uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x;
    }

    //call loop to go through the balloons for each touch.
    //[self CollisionCheck];

        NSUInteger h;
        float dist, tempvelx, tempvely, temp2velx, temp2vely;;

        for (h=1; h <= NumBalloons; ++h) {
            //check if balloon is too close
            if (CurBalloon == h) { //skip the check ifit's the same balloon
            } else {
                dist = distanceBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos);
                if (dist <= (kBalloonNear)) { //balloon's touching

                    tempvelx = uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x;
                    tempvely = uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y;
                    temp2velx = uBalloon[h].Vel_x;
                    temp2vely = uBalloon[h].Vel_y;

                    tempvelx = (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - uBalloon[h].Vel_x) * (sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos)))*(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - uBalloon[h].Vel_x) * (sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos))) - (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y - uBalloon[h].Vel_y) * sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) * cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) + uBalloon[h].Vel_x;

                    tempvely = (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y - uBalloon[h].Vel_y) * (cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos))) * (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y - uBalloon[h].Vel_y) * (cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos))) - (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - uBalloon[h].Vel_x) * sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) * cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) + uBalloon[h].Vel_y;

                    temp2velx = (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - uBalloon[h].Vel_x) * (cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos))) * (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - uBalloon[h].Vel_x) * (cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos))) + (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y - uBalloon[h].Vel_y) * sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) * cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) + uBalloon[h].Vel_x;

                    temp2vely = (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y - uBalloon[h].Vel_y) * (sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos)))*(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y - uBalloon[h].Vel_y) * (sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos,uBalloon[h].pos))) - (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - uBalloon[h].Vel_x) * sinf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) * cosf(angleBetweenPoints(uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos, uBalloon[h].pos)) + uBalloon[h].Vel_y;

                    uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = tempvelx;  
                    uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = tempvely;
                    uBalloon[h].Vel_x = temp2velx;  //set to old value of CurBalloon balloon.
                    uBalloon[h].Vel_y = temp2vely;

                }
            }
        }


    if (fabsf(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x) >= kBalloonMaxSpeed) uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = kBalloonMaxSpeed;
    if (fabsf(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y) >= kBalloonMaxSpeed) uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = kBalloonMaxSpeed;
    if (fabsf(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x) <= -kBalloonMaxSpeed) uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = -kBalloonMaxSpeed;
    if (fabsf(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y) <= -kBalloonMaxSpeed) uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = -kBalloonMaxSpeed;



    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y > KBalloonSpeed) { //if travellCurBalloonng fast, slow CurBalloont up fast to normal speed
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y - kBalloonSlowRate;
    }
    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x > KBalloonSpeed) { //if travellCurBalloonng fast, slow CurBalloont up fast to normal speed
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - kBalloonSlowRate;
    }
    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y < KBalloonSpeed) { //if travellCurBalloonng fast, slow CurBalloont up fast to normal speed
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y + kBalloonSlowRate;
    }
    if (uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x < KBalloonSpeed) { //if travellCurBalloonng fast, slow CurBalloont up fast to normal speed
        uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x + kBalloonSlowRate;
    }


    //slow to 0 if velocCurBalloonty CurBalloons CurBalloonnsCurBalloonde the slow rate
    if (fabsf(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x) <= kBalloonSlowRate) uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = 0;
    if (fabsf(uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y) <= kBalloonSlowRate) uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y = 0;

    uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x = uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x - kBalloonFallRate; //keep movCurBalloonng down     

    //add velocCurBalloonty to poCurBalloonnts
    uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.y= uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.y + uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_y;    
    uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.x = uBalloon[CurBalloon].pos.x + uBalloon[CurBalloon].Vel_x;

    }
}
```

Here's the functions written in c that are used for distance and the angle.  I'm even making sure to never have a sqrt(-1) and division by 0:

```
 CGFloat distanceBetweenPoints (CGPoint first, CGPoint second) {
    CGFloat deltaX = second.x - first.x;
    CGFloat deltaY = second.y - first.y;
    if ((deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY ) == -1) {
        return sqrtf(-.99);
    } else {
    return sqrtf(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY );
    }
}

    CGFloat angleBetweenPoints(CGPoint first, CGPoint second) {

    if (first.x - second.x == 0)  {
        return (pi / 2);
    } else {
        return atanf((first.y-second.y) / (first.x - second.x));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If uBalloon is an array your iteration should be between 0:(n-1).

E.g.

```
for (CurBalloon=0; CurBalloon < NumBalloons; ++CurBalloon)
{
  uBalloon[curBalloon] // blah
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[...]
if ((deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY ) == -1) {
    return sqrtf(-.99);
} else {
[...]
```

I think this is your problem (or one of them). You can't take the square root of a negative number (and it doesn't matter if it's -1 or -.99).

Comment: Also, sum of two squares can never be negative. Not that you can reliably check for equality using ==, anyway.

Comment: OK, so this is unnecessary, but not a problem.

Comment: I thought it might not ever go negative... deleting that part, then.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the source of your error, but this function isn't quite right:

```
CGFloat angleBetweenPoints(CGPoint first, CGPoint second) {

if (first.x - second.x == 0)  {
        return (pi / 2);
} else {
        return atanf((first.y-second.y) / (first.x - second.x));
}
```

This will always return an angle between -pi/2 and +pi/2, and it may return an incorrect result if `first.x - second.x` is very small and close to 0, but not exactly 0.  Instead, just use [atan2](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atan2):

```
CGFloat angleBetweenPoints(CGPoint first, CGPoint second) {
    return atan2f(first.y - second.y, first.x - second.x);
}
```

`atan2()` returns the full range of angles from -pi to +pi, and handles the edge cases appropriately.  This probably won't affect you since you're just taking the sin/cos of the resulting angle.  You're doing so in a very inefficient manner, however -- you're calling `angleBetweenPoints()` 8 (!) times when the result is the same very time, and taking 4 `sin()`s and 4 `cos()`s.  You could skip all of the trigonometry and just use the geometry of similar triangles to get the same results.

Comment: Thank You, I haven't been working with objective-C long.  I changed it to atan2f.  Also, thanks for pointing out the repeated calls.